# sockets block on send for some reason

Tags: python, sockets

Trying to implement compressed communication over raw sockets using SocketServer. My handler class does this to read

```
       raw_message = []
       while True:
           data = self.request.recv(1024)
           if not data:
               break
           raw_message.append(data)
       raw_message = ''.join(raw_message)
```

and then it tries to decompress and send me a reply. Where my client code goes like this

```
    try:
        sock.connect(('myhost', 8075))
    except Exception as e:
        print('failed to connect', e)
    compressed = zlib.compress(bytes(payload, 'utf-8'))
    print('payload length: ', len(payload))
    print('compressed length: ', len(compressed))
    try:
        sock.sendall(compressed)

    except Exception as e:
        print('failed to send', e)
    print('sent')
    data = sock.recv(4096)
    print('data: ', zlib.decompress(data))
```

Somehow the server never gets out of the "while True:" loop even though every tutorial says it should work this way. Anything I am doing wrong?

Edit: Looks like continuous communication over a single socket requires a bit of planning, where both ends know when communication starts and stops. I expected this to be handled by send() and recv() but apparently it is not.

Comment: Well, of course it never ends. That's why we use while True. When would you like to end the loop ?

Comment: Do you see the if not data: break? I want the loop to end when client is done sending.

Comment: Client need to notify that it finished sending, using socket.shutdown (not socket.close which close both reading/writing part of the socket). Your condition is not enough. It just works if there's no data to be sent

Comment: Well, if I shut down the write socket, how do I send data again?

Comment: Client sockets are normally only used for one exchange (or a small set of sequential exchanges). Please have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Comment: I have looked. I don't think it says anything about sockets only working for one exchange.